# Wrapper around malloc will it work?

Tags: c

I am trying to write a wrapper function around `malloc`. Here is the code I have written, but I am not sure will it work.

Can someone take a look at it and let me know if it works, and if not why not?

```
int main()
{
    int i=1;
    char *k;
    while(i<3)
    {
        i++;
        k = (char *) CountMalloc(1024);
        printf(" Total mem : %d \n Memory Address:%x \n",Totalmem,k);
    }

    printf(" Exiting\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the function where I am allocating the memory and trying to pass the void 
pointer. I know this works if I declare a pointer and if I pass its address to my function and in the function call `malloc` and assign the address to the passed pointer. But I want to know if the following code works:

```
void * CountMalloc( int size )
{
    char *p;
    Totalmem += size;
    return ( malloc (size) );
}
```

Comment: better use `size_t` for the size argument, but otherwise I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Don't cast `malloc` in C. Also, usually we write `main(void)`.

Comment: You should see some warnings if you compile with `-Wall`. I'll let you explore this to see why this is so.

Comment: "I want to know if the following code works" ...so why don't run it and check yourself?

Comment: @cdhowie The equivalent part only applies to `int argc, char *argv[]`. Look at: 10)  In case of no arguments it must be void.

Comment: @self. In doing some more research I see I have stepped into a holy war where the validity of `int main()` seems to be hotly debated, with one side saying that `void x()` and `void x(void)` mean the same thing in C99 (`x` takes no arguments) and therefore they are equivalent, with the other side pointing out the lack of `int main()` listed as an option in 5.1.2.2.1.  I will continue with my interpretation and leave you to continue with yours, as I doubt anyone is going to be convinced in this situation (and SO comments are probably not the correct forum for this discussion).

Comment: I see in n897 examples with "int main( )".. 6.2.2 table

Comment: @cdhowie I'm neutral, give me a good argument. Interestingly there are two code examples in the latest standard with just int main() and only one with int main( void ).

Comment: Isn't that a whole other Q&A, thus not the right thing for the comments?

Comment: @self. I quote the option *"It shall be defined with a return type of int and with no parameters, or ..."* -- given the rest of the C99 spec, I would say that `int main()` is a way to define `main` with *"a return type of int and with no parameters"*.  The particular text given (`int main(void) ...`) I see as an example of a definition that would meet these criteria, *but not the only one possible*.

Comment: @self. To support this, I cite 6.7.5.3: *"The special case of an unnamed parameter of type void as the only item in the list specifies that the function has no parameters. ... An empty list in a function declarator that is part of a definition of that function specifies that the function has no parameters."*

Comment: @cdhowie Awesome, now it is official :) ( save the links! )

Comment: @self. I will clarify though: when declaring (not defining) `main` this is not the case.  `int main();` would not be valid, while `int main(void);` would.  However, when supplying a definition for the function, `int main() { /* ... */ }` and `int main(void) { /* ... */ }` are considered equivalent.  But who declares `main` anyway?  ;)

Comment: @cdhowie `int main()` and `int main(void)` certainly do not mean the same thing; the question is whether the C standard says they are both valid.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Can you explain how they differ when used in a function definition (not declaration)?

Comment: @cdhowie the version with `(void)` forms a *prototype* which means that the compiler will check the number and types of arguments to the function. The other version doesn't (you just get undefined behaviour when a non-matching call is attempted). Example `int main() { main(5,6,7,8,9); }`

Answer (score 5):

A few notes:

The argument to `malloc()` is declared to be `size_t`, therefore the `size` parameter to `CountMalloc()` should also be `size_t`.

You don't check the result of `malloc()` to see if the allocation succeeded.  Consider doing this instead:

```
void * CountMalloc(size_t size)
{
    void * allocation = malloc(size);
    if (allocation) {
        Totalmem += size;
    }
    return allocation;
}
```

However, note that the total amount of memory allocated is likely to be higher.  Most `malloc()` implementations allocate more memory than you request so that they can store some information about the allocation prior to the location in memory that it returns.

Otherwise, I see no serious problems that would prevent the code from having the effect you intended.

Comment: Just adding a bit of clarification to the "[M]ost `malloc()` implementations" bit.  Any `malloc` that wanted its matching `free` to actually do anything would need to store the size of the object somewhere.  Otherwise, `free` would have no idea how big a piece of memory had been passed to it.  It is usually stored it the byte(s) preceding the pointer returned by `malloc()` as this allows a very simple and fast way to retrieve that info.

Comment: cdhowie dont you think allcation is local varialbe and vanishes as soon the function is returned . it may work some time but may not work always as per my understanding.

Comment: @user3161006 No. `malloc()` allocates a block of memory on the heap, not the stack.  This memory remains allocated until either `free()` is called on that allocation, or the program terminates.

Comment: you are write , memory allocated from heap . but the pointer to that memory is stored in stack . and that will be lost when the function returns, So ideally when the control goes back to main there is no variable called allocation correct me if am wronge.

Comment: @user3161006 The pointer only *points to* the allocation.  For example, you might return such a pointer to the caller, in which case the memory can still be referenced.  Vanilla C does not protect you from memory leaks like other languages might -- you must ensure that every call to `malloc()` has a matching call to `free()`, otherwise the memory will be leaked.

Answer (score 0):

While your code will keep track of the total amount of memory request via `malloc()`, it isn't really keeping track of the total amount of memory used by the objects that are returned.  Most allocators won't return objects of arbitrary sizes, but rather have pools of fixed sized objects (4 bytes, 8 bytes, etc.) and return the smallest object that can meet the size requested.

Even if it would allow objects of arbitrary size, it would still often round up the size of the memory block returned, depending on if the hardware allowed for byte or word addressing, or to maximize object reusabilty.

Finally, like I stated in a comment to another answer, the object will often have a hidden header that stores the size of the object, so that a subsequent `free()` can know how large a block is being returned.